# Oracle VPD Column Restriction

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a Virtual Private Database that limits database access. I am stuck on how to restrict the user from viewing all columns. My assignment asks to limit the user to two columns:

*Design and implement a Virtual Private Database that limits database access. Your design should be based on two of your columns and two of your tables. (Hint: where col1 = value1 AND col2 = value2).*

Here are my current DDL statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth_client(
 v_schema IN VARCHAR2,
 v_objname IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 con VARCHAR2 (200); 
BEGIN 
 con := 'SALES_REP_ID = 4111';
 RETURN (con); 
END auth_client; 
/

BEGIN 
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
 object_schema => 'general_manager', 
 object_name => 'client', 
 policy_name => 'client_policy', 
 policy_function => 'auth_client',
 sec_relevant_cols => 'sales_rep_id'); 
END; 
/
```

From my understanding, the sec_relevant_cols statement is suppose to restrict all but the specified columns in the query but all columns still show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VPD allows you only to hide value from column not remove column from result;

```
create table vpd_table 
as select mod(level,2) as nr,level lv from dual connect by level < 100;

select * from vpd_table;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auth_function(
 v_schema IN VARCHAR2,
 v_objname IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
 con VARCHAR2 (200); 
BEGIN 
 con := 'nr = 1';
 RETURN (con); 
END ; 
/

BEGIN 
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
 object_name => 'vpd_table', 
 policy_name => 'client_policy', 
 policy_function => 'auth_function',
 sec_relevant_cols => 'nr', 
 sec_relevant_cols_opt => dbms_rls.ALL_ROWS); 
END; 
/

begin 
DBMS_RLS.DROP_POLICY(null, 'vpd_table', 'client_policy');
end;
```

What is important.

`sec_relevant_cols` - list of sensitive columns. `'col1 col2' or 'col1,col2'` - both format are supported.

`sec_relevant_cols_opt` - work only with `sec_relevant_cols`. If is `dbms_rls.ALL_ROWS`  - for sensitive column oracle insted of orignals value dispaly null. 
/

If yon want remove columns from result you have to create view. And grant access only to vie.